# Estimating GaN HEMT junction temperature

Tags: temperature, thermal, junction, rdson, gan

I think it's quite a simple question, but the solution is not so obvious for me.

I know the equation Tj=Ptot×Rth+Ta, the thermal resistance Rthj-a and RDSon temperature dependance come from the datasheet: [GS61004B datasheet](https://gansystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/GS61004B-DS-Rev-221201.pdf)

Let's assume that in my application:

1. Average drain current is 8.5 A
2. Thermal resistance is 28°C/W
3. Ta is 25°C
4. Total switching energy loss is 0.00000572 J (Eon is 0.00000329 J and Eoff is 0.00000242 J)
5. Switching frequency is 200 kHz
6. RDSon for Tj = 25°C is 0.016 Ohms

So Ptot can be calculated as (Eon+Eoff)x200kHz + IDxIDxRDSon. By taking into account 0.016 Ohms (RDSon for Tj = 25°C from the datasheet) I get Tj = 28x(0.00000571x200000 + 8.5x8.5x0.016) + 25 = 89.34°C. I know that RDSon is temperature dependant and for roughly 90°C it is approximately 0.0248 Ohms, so won't Tj now be 28x(0.00000571x200000 + 8.5x8.5x0.0248) + 25 = 107°C?
I feel that I'm in an endless loop and would like to know how to calculate correctly.

Comment: Please use engineering notation instead of 0.000000… for readability. Depending on how accurate you need it, you need to either use a differential equation or iterate as you have done for a few steps. If you intend to have higher than 25 degrees max ambient, you are often best off with either a fan or better silicon in the first place.

Comment: Well, you're probably not in an endless loop.  Just one that takes a handful of iterations to arrive at an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, obviously it was not an endless loop, just took quite a bunch iterations. After a few of them I managed to estiamte a temperature, for which my RDSon estimation was equal to the datasheet RDSon(Tj) value. My intuition with the endless loop was false.

Answer (score 1):

Besides arguments in the comments, you can't calculate the conduction loss by squaring the average current and multiplying with resistance. This will *underestimate* the conduction loss.

Instead, you have to multiply the on-state conduction loss (power) with duty cycle.

Comment: Allow me to correct what I wrote: the formula I used for the current is (IDmax-IDmin)/2*D

Comment: @Den yeah. that is wrong. run the numbers through my answer and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I mean I understand what you mean and I'm thankful for you valuable contribution, but the assumption is that RDSon is weakly dependant on ID. Let me note that what I'm trying to do is strictly theoretical

Comment: @Den R is mainly dependent on temperature. And if you use a wrong formula for the conduction loss, you can easily be several 10°C off in the end. That is all I wanted to note. :)